# Bcrypt hashpw and checkpw are comparing slightly different encrypted passwords and failing authentication

Tags: authentication, flask, encryption, hash, bcrypt

looking for your help.

I am using Bcrypts hashpw and checkpw methods as part of a User class (db.Model structure) in Python to facillitate User sign up and encrpyted password saving. (and later login/authentication).

I have been able to make use of Bcrypts hashpw method to store a salted and hashed pw in the db as part of the user.

When looking to compare our user input on login, to the stored database, It is giving me two slightly different encrpyted keys, and returning false, therefore failing the log in.

I cant seem to see what is going wrong, and I have achieved this successfully before, and even utilized the majority of the code from this source. There are no dependencies from the previous project that it worked before. So I must be missing/mistyping something here

Here is my sign up class method on our User class. This works fine to the best of my knowledge.

```
@classmethod
def signup(cls, username, email, image_url, password):
    """Sign up user.

    Hashes password and adds user to system.
    """

    byte_pwd = password.encode('utf-8')
    my_salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed_pwd = bcrypt.hashpw(byte_pwd,my_salt)

    user = User(
        username=username,
        email=email,
        image_url=image_url,
        password=hashed_pwd
    )

    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return user
```

And here is the authentication class method, which is functional but not rendering the matching encrypted password stored in the db, for some reason.

```
@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, username, password):
    """Find user with `username` and `password`"""
    user = cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    print(user)
    print(user.password.encode('utf-8'))

    byte_pwd = password.encode('utf-8')
    my_salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
    hashed_pwd = bcrypt.hashpw(byte_pwd, my_salt)

    if user:
        is_auth = bcrypt.checkpw(user.password.encode('utf-8'), hashed_pwd)
        if is_auth:
            return user

    return False
```

Comment: You use `checkpw()` in a wrong way. Have a look at the example in the *bcrypt* documentation: [*Password hashing*](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#password-hashing). `checkpw()` requires the password to verify as 1st parameter and the hash (from signup stored in the DB) as 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For the password check, you simply call `checkpw` with the previously stored hashed password. Do not generate a new salt and do not hash it again.

```py
@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, username, password):
    """Find user with `username` and `password`"""
    user = cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    byte_pwd = password.encode('utf-8')

    if user:
        is_auth = bcrypt.checkpw(byte_pwd, user.password)
        if is_auth:
            return user

    return False
```